# Powershell - Using -Filter in Get-ADuser to move users with spefific names

Tags: powershell

Im currently working on a script for a client. The script should only run on AD users with specific name-codes.

The Get-ADuser should only target users who have the sAMAccountName K00001 to K30000. However, I am pretty lost to how I should workaround the -Filter to target users with a spefific letter and range of numbers in their sAMAccountName.

Comment: post the script you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD cmdlet `-filter` only does wildcard globbing. So you'd be able to filter just `K*` with that filter and you would need to do the rest of the filtering with `Where-Object` with which you can use regex with to filter those results for entries that start with K followed by 5 digits.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like 'K*'" | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -match '^K/d{5}'}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, mate. Played around with your script and eventually made it work!